# storyboard has become taxing on system; any drawbacks to using nibs for isolated views?

Tags: ios, storyboard

Lately, when I navigate to my storyboard, I get the pinwheel animation for a few seconds and the laptop's fan goes into high gear for about a minute. This used not to happen, and I almost never hear the fan otherwise.

Firstly, is this indicative that there might be something wrong in my storyboard, or is it inevitable as the storyboard grows? The storyboard has about 25 VCs right now.

It will be adding many more VCs to the storyboard in the future. Some of them will be isolated, i.e., have no segues to any other VCs. Should I use nibs for those VCs in order to improve performance? Are there any drawbacks to using nibs in addition to a storyboard? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this will happen as the complexity of your storyboard increases. There are no technical issues using nibs in addition to a storyboard.

I prefer to use a third solution and have multiple storyboards each of which contains a logically distinct sub-set of view controllers. This retains the flexibility afforded by storyboards without allowing them to become too unwieldy.

Comment: +1 this is how I have found it most efficient. Both to edit and to run. I have a workflow in my app for adding/removing "favourites". It uses a nag controller and 3 views. I put this entire workflow into a separate Storyboard and load the storyboard and present it modally where needed.

Comment: oh wow.. i had completely forgotten how responsive a storyboard could be!

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in http://www.raywenderlich.com/51992/storyboards-vs-nibs-vs-code-the-great-debate. Also read the comments.